# Sorting two-way cell connections with priority

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, data-structures, sorting

I have a two dimensional grid of cells. In this simulation, cells may request to switch position with another cell. The request also has a priority.

The problem is that Im having a hard time coming up with a good way to structure this. If A wants to switch with B, and B also wants to switch with A, they currently can be switched and switched back in a single logic tick (which should be impossible).

The solution probably involves making sure (A to B)==(B to A) and insertion sorting them into a list by their priority.

Does such data structure have a name? Anyone recognise the problem and can provide some good links for reading?

Comment: i don't understand the details of the problem very well. how does it switch twice on a single logic tick? are the switch "requests" processed imediately or later.

Comment: In the first step of the logic tick, every cell registers the cell (or cells) it wants to switch place with. When thats done all the switches are actually made, if a cell wants to switch with more than one other cell the switch with the highest priority is picked. The problems arise when two cells wants to switch with each other and both file two separate SwitchRequests. If both are processed, nothing will have happened since they switched and switched back.

Comment: i know this doesn't help your problem but it's another corner case: what if two different cells want to swap with the same one? will one swap and then the other swap with the one it didn't intend to?

Comment: The basic rule is that any one cell can only go through one swap each tick. If multiple cells request a swap with another cell, the highest priority takes precedence. In case of identical priority, the first request is processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say that I've come across an example like this before, so I don't know what it would be called, but perhaps something like this would work...

**Cell** - a class or struct

- CellId
- XCoordinate
- YCoordinate

**SwitchRequest** - a class or struct

- RequestingCell
- TargetCell
- Priority
- CanSwitch

**SwitchRequests** - an array of SwitchRequests

**AlreadySwitchedCells** - an array of Cells

**Algorithm**

For each tick:

```
clear AlreadySwitchedCells
build list of SwitchRequests
sort SwitchRequests by Priority (highest to lowest)
loop through each SwitchRequest
{
  if (RequestingCell is not in AlreadySwitchedCells and TargetCell is not in AlreadySwitchedCells)
  {
    add RequestingCell and TargetCell to AlreadySwitchedCells
    SwapCellIds(RequestingCell, TargetCell)
  }
}
```

Note: There are some options here, like whether you should make the coordinates properties of a Cell or just store the CellIds in an two-dimensional array, but hopefully this gives you a starting point.

Comment: Forgot to accept this, and I doubt the question will see much more activity. Thanks! :)